# How can I create a type array from an object that contains the keys?

Tags: arrays, typescript, typescript-generics

I think for my scenario there must be a better way to avoid duplicate code, but I can't get it to work..

I have an object like this:

```js
const sectionTypes = {
  foo: ...,
  bar: ...
} as const;
```

Based on the object keys, I need to create an array of objects. But only a type array, not a real one.

something like this:

```ts
type SectionArray = [
  { type: 'foo', ... },
  { type: 'bar', ... }
]
```

currently I am creating the array manual, as I have not found a way to create an array dynamically based on the keys. Is there any way to avoid the repetitions? Thanks!

Playground Link with a more detailed recreation: [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwiAtgBwIwwLwwBTIE4jIQBcMA3gG4CGANgK4CmpYdiARg3gL4CUmAfOS4AoUJFgIUAJkw58hEuSpgQUABacAarUaloeAJZgA5rwFDhwqAE9kDGADMQIWQAUqeKogZROEADw2diAO8Eho-JYMAB7IIHiwYtAwEAzAUAbgACq2DBCyZMIwMKAoqKSSaAA0RSXhUhX1NVwwVPlJUADclkH2ANIM1vlYANaDITC9E6npmWA5dhDdvWEo4AxgUMOTudNpGdm5Sz25MACqqZXrm-5ZMDG+YAAm+QNDgliFxb2kWd3FqSgGRMincnm8vjwASuYA2WwA2lkALr8eEABiR3S43WEAHpcZM1AZ8hA1CA6DQnjAOCU8AwqL4qU9rGAvAZgLQaNYrKcAILUAw0KhsGgMGFw7bw2oXMXha5QfwAclKaEV-BqxRl4puyvqauEmKisXisBWAGV9nNZPyqILhaLtQiWOxOIbROBkqTyZSAEIMC2zcCkAMHMDwpGyKXFMg7OykXVlRVVFI+YHGRQx6j0JgwdAtLga8ixnMJ5BSJMpoFGdOkGPKVQaPDabPxpwgRUwfOF-GE4kpMkUqlegDurTA9zwBDwtRjPxgpfLycBaYzMCzulznc7BqAA)

Comment: Can keys in `sectionTypes` have multiple entries in the `SectionArray` type? Would an empty array satisfy the type? What do you think of [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGAzEIAXDAEQkA02M8AhgE7FmUC+A3JplAJ4AOApjADySAIJ06NLqhhiJXADxYc3fsQDWfLiFwwVfbXCTtmAPg6hIsKH2gBGYsMSzJ0gNpUlOXbz6N8ICipmShxPZR9GWjoSIMwAXXZMC2hdGygAJgdRcRc0d1CqcNVSf0CcYI9C72KSKJjykIwqvT8CMpgKgq9q31I62ITzcBTraABmLKccqTzBpOGrNIAWSecZmHym7pa+mgAveo7KQaA)?

Comment: I need to access the key in the array object apart from the type value. Maybe [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmwoEtwBUCeAHeEYF4YBvAKBhgDMQQAuGAcnoBoyYAjAQwCc7GWBfGBzyhIUANwkSUbPBgBBMCCgALeF3lcuHDAWKt6VEPToBGFuXqcuJmACYS-KTJwwAkgBN4HPZu0YAHiIXeDoAa3gMEAoYEOi4RBR0WQgmGAA3DgAbAFdQhSVVdT8dAG0IqJi4mIQkVDBMHAgAXRh+AD4pUWgYHIhkMABzT286EZ9CUtJyELoAIms5ixgAehW4FRAcrI8YD2QILCydITAYdS4QLlZM3PzTR2agA) will give a better insight.

Comment: What about [this](https://tsplay.dev/WyXnxm) solution utilizing distributive conditional types to get the desired type? You should also edit the question with the example in your playground.

Comment: @Wing Thank you for the input! I added a new playground link to the question and I hope it is now a bit clearer to understand. Unfortunately, your idea does not work that way.

Answer (score 0):

```js
type SectionKeys = typeof sectionTypes

type Section = {type: keyof SectionKeys}

const array: Section[] = [{type: "foo"}]
```

This way, by annotating the `Section[]` type, you will be forced by typescript to provide an object with a property type that accepts only the keys of `sectionTypes`

Providing more props won't cause any typescript error, but there is also no restriction on it. But you got the idea. You can expand your type in whatever way you want.

Comment: thanks. Maybe [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmwoEtwBUCeAHeEYF4YBvAKBhgDMQQAuGAcnoBoyYAjAQwCc7GWBfGBzyhIUANwkSUbPBgBBMCCgALeF3lcuHDAWKt6VEPToBGFuXqcuJmACYS-KTJwwAkgBN4HPZu0YAHiIXeDoAa3gMEAoYEOi4RBR0WQgmGAA3DgAbAFdQhSVVdT8dAG0IqJi4mIQkVDBMHAgAXRh+AD4pUWgYHIhkMABzT286EZ9CUtJyELoAIms5ixgAehW4FRAcrI8YD2QILCydITAYdS4QLlZM3PzTR2bnWRgAZU3tjwAhOUISwNY03IsVkvCMzFY5FueToimUag0WjKhmo9Ce5H4AB9AZCQTheNYIcCMtkYQV4cUkRhSlZuGjWE5OiRurA+gNBu8tjsfnROZ8fnopqxZjAFtwljdSfkHPxmkA) will give you a better insight into the scenario.